# How to add external xml file to php parser

Tags: php, xml

I try to parse an XML file, the code I have only works when I add the XML directly in the PHP code, but I need to get it working with an external file.

I tried many ways to get it working, but without success.

UPD. No advises were helpful, I found solution by myself.

Thank you for all who try to help me.

```
<?php

  $url = "link to file";
  $domSrc = file_get_contents($url);
  $dom = new DomDocument();
  $dom->loadXML( $domSrc );

        while(is_object($finance = $dom->getElementsByTagName("item")->item($i)))
        {
                 foreach($finance->childNodes as $nodename)
                 {
                        if($nodename->nodeName=='id')
                            {
                            echo "<p>$nodename->nodeValue</p>";
                            }
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please define *external file*. What does external mean here? Also please provide an XML sample from that file. Also enable error reporting and logging, that should give you more hints, see: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456)

Answer (score 0):

The DOMDocument has several methods to load contents. In your case DOMDocument::load() should be the right choice. Just replace:

```
$doc->loadXML($xml);
```

with

```
$doc->load($xml);
```

The method has full support for the PHP streamwrappers. But is a good idea to always use an absolute path and not rely on the current working directory.

```
$xml = __DIR__.'/move.xml';
```

Comment: Replace the line as you wrote, nothing happens.

Comment: Sounds like your error reporting is to low, you should get at least a message that the file could not be read.

Answer (score -1):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('giveYourUrl');
```

try it